# How to use detect changes in elements of an array using provider?

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-provider

I started developing my first app with flutter and I have some questions.

I have a screen that contains a Horizontal ListView where each item represents a month and occupy the entire screen. Each item is another list of itens. It's basically a list showing expenses for every month. I'm controlling state using Provider, and I'm having trouble to detect changes in a month. For example, I'm in january, but I added an expense in february, so the february item must detect the change and rewrite. I haven't been able to do it so far. Here is the screenshots of the app:

[image]

[image]

I have a provider that has an array of "Periods". And a "Period" is a class that represents a month, and contains an array of expenses.

I guess I'm not organising my data the right away, I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

EDIT:

So, I watched this video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I, and that helped me a little at least on how to detect changes in nested providers. I basically did this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  final financeiro = Provider.of<Financeiro>(context);
    return ImprovedListView.builder(
      controller: _listController,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: financeiro.periodos.length,
      itemSize: size.width,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      initialScrollOffset: financeiro.indexMesAtual * size.width,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
        final periodo = financeiro.periodos[index]; //get a piece of the list and pass to another change notifier provider
        return ChangeNotifierProvider<Periodo>.value(
          value: periodo,
          child: PeriodoFinanceiro(
            key: ValueKey('${periodo.ano}${periodo.mes}'),
            index: index,
            scrollTo: scrollTo,
            carregarDadosIniciais: carregarDadosIniciais,
            excluirLancamento: excluirLancamento,
          ),
        );
      };
}
```

Now I just have to figure out how to better control the scrolloffset  of the list when its re-rendered.

Thanks

Comment: If possible, could you add some code? Without code, the best I can guess is you are not calling `notifyListeners()` when you change the array in you model. Hope it helps:)

Comment: More than a picture we need code to be able to help you :) but as suggested by @Jack maybe you just forgot the `notifyListeners()`

Comment: @Jack and Tizianoreica I watched a video and managed to figure it out. I put the solution on the post. Now I just have to figure out how to defined the scrollOffset position when the list is re rendered (after I delete something, I have to pull all the information again). Thanks 